# Assembly, read in 2 ints

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, user-input, x86-64

I've just started to learn assembler (2 days ago) for x86 arch (but I program on x86_64 see below). I want to read in 2 numbers and for that I use Linux system calls (64 bit system). Well I looked up the corresponding numbers for read/write in unitstd_64.h and seems to work. But one thing bothers me (first the code):

```
section .data
prompt1 db "Enter a number: ", 0
lenMsg equ $-prompt1
outmsg db "Entered: ", 0
lenOut equ $-outmsg

section .bss
input1 resd 1
input2 resd 1

segment .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, prompt1
mov rdx, lenMsg
syscall

;read input number 1
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 2
mov rsi, input1
mov rdx, 1
syscall

;prompt another number
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, prompt1
mov rdx, lenMsg
syscall

;read input number 1
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 2
mov rsi, input2 
mov rdx, 1
syscall

;exit correctly
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

The program does the following:

1. Shows prompt1
2. Let the user enter a number
3. Shows prompt1 again
4. quits (should'nt it let the user enter a number instead of quitting?)

Why is the fourth syscall simply ignored? Thanks in advance.

edit: 
I use nasm. Object file created with nasm -f elf64 bla.asm. Linked with ld -o bla bla.o

Comment: You only `read()` a single `char` each, leaving enough `char`s in the pipe for the second `read()` to finish immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at  first I had to think about it but i managed to get it work although I'm not competely sure why :-) I changed to value in rdx to be greater than 1. Input1 and input2 are of 'length' double word (i.e. 4 bytes). Does the valuein rdx (let's say it is 4)  mean 'read 4 bytes' ?

Comment: I'd recommend a look at the manpage for `read()` and `write()`. Short story: Yes, you pass the count of bytes your buffer can hold (aside: these syscalls return the number of bytes they actually read/wrote, which can be less than the count you passed). BTW, you're reading from `STDERR_FILENO` instead of `STDIN_FILENO`. Bizarrely, this works fine in my (limited) testing.

Comment: @EOF I will read the manual for read()/write(). In unitstd_64.h on my linux (debian jessie) it only says #define __NR_read 0. Well maybe I will know more when I'm finished reading the man page.

Comment: Me again: How do you know I'm reading in from `STDERR_FILENO` instead of `STDIN_FILENO` ?

Comment: `mov rdi, 2`. You load the constant `2` into the register used to pass the file-descriptor. `STDIN_FILENO == 0, STDOUT_FILENO == 1, STDERR_FILENO == 2`.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is clear to me and I will continue learning. Guess I won't ask those questions in the near future I was just a little bit impatient and needed to know :-P